# SEO - very low Domain Authority

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, backlinks

I've a website for about 10 years ... we're a team developing websites .... we've been on the first page on google for the keywords we wanted but it has been 40 days that we moved to page 2 on google search .

I'm not an expert in seo but since then we've been working on the content and our blog for about 30 days and we've made unique and very good quality of contents .

also make lots of youtube movies and worked on socials to get us back to page one

we came to page one again for about 3-4 days and again go back to page 2 . we're still losing .

this is the moz result :
[image]

this is the ahrefs result
[image]

there is a thing I'm suspect , we're making shopping website and now we've about 100 sites , on the footer of each site we've a back to our site , for example a website has about 5000 product pages and we've out backlink on each of them . these site are new and has no DA and rank in google .

can these backlinks damaging us ?

Comment: Google doesn't use Moz domain authority as a ranking factor.  Google keeps its own metrics and they work differently.   Google doesn't say how its own metrics are computed, but having an issue with the Moz metrics isn't going to change how Google measures your site.

Comment: @I'm just saying that I've too many backlinks , can these backlinks destroy my site ?

Answer (score 2):

A backlink profile with a small Referring domains to Backlinks ratio will hurt your site in most fields since it doesn't look natural. However, as far as I know in the site building industry, it shouldn't be a bad thing.

There are a number of possibilities here:

1. You have all those links as dofollow, that's pretty bad and should be changed to nofollow as soon as possible. Allegedly nofollow links have no effect on SEO. However nofollow [links have been shown to help SEO and site traffic overall](https://neilpatel.com/blog/nofollow-link-answers/). Besides, Google quite certainly can tell that this is a footer link, therefore expecting it to be a nofllow.
2. Some of the sites you built got hacked and were injected with bad topics. You have links from them, and therefore Google thinks you are related somehow to those topics.
3. Some of the sites may be doing blackhat SEO, which penalizes them, making the links from them useless at best and hurting your site at most.

I would suggest to **sometimes** just mention your companies name instead of linking if the site is really large (Emphasis on someties). I would also suggest that you make sure none of them does blackhat SEO or got hacked and injected with toxic links or topics. Good luck.